# Django validate DateTime

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have booking API endpoint and i want to check each time user want booking hall if DateTime and hall that user want booking is available.

I try this queryset in validate in Serializer to check if this time and hall is booking or not

```py
def validate(self, data):
        BookingModel.objects.filter(date_time__exact=data['date_time']).get(hall_id__iexact=data['hall']).exists()
```

but it give this Error: `BookingModel matching query does not exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey get method raise an error when no objects found, so try the below query

```
BookingModel.objects.filter(date_time__exact=data['date_time'], hall_id=data['hall']).exists()
```

Comment: it give me this Error: Related Field got invalid lookup: iexact